# jsp to servlet send array

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to send multiple checkbox with the same name to servlet, but I only get the first checkbox selected. for example if I select the first and second checkbox I noly get the value 1.

note: I need set the same name on checkbox to use the plugin jquery validation-engine

form data:

```
<form name="formSubmit" id="formActConv" method="post" action="javascript:formSubmit();">
<div style="width: 500px;">
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_1" value="1" >group</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_2" value="2" >group1</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_3" value="3" >group2</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_4" value="4" >group3</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_5" value="5" >group4</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_6" value="6" >group5</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_7" value="7" >group5</div>
<div><input name="group" type="checkbox" id="group_8" value="8" >group6</div>
</div>
</form>
```

send data:

```
function formSubmit()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:servletName,
        async: false,
        data: $("#formSubmit").serialize()",
        /*beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", process);
        },*/
        success: function (data) {
            window.location = document.location.origin;
        }
    });
}
```

method to show data:

```
public void showDatos(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) params.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Attribute Name - " + paramName + ", Value - " + request.getParameter(paramName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're using `HttpServletRequest#getParameters`.

Comment: yes, I use this method to show data public void showDatos(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) params.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Attribute Name - " + paramName + ", Value - " + request.getParameter(paramName));
        }
    }

Comment: The method you want to use is `getParameters` (note the lowercase **s** at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.getParameterValues("group")` for reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: yes, I use this method to show data public void showDatos(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) params.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Attribute Name - " + paramName + ", Value - " + request.getParameter(paramName));
        }
    }

Comment: add this to ur question and is it not printing any data?